# django-registration invalid activation key error but user account gets activated

Tags: django, django-registration

When I click on activation link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/core/auth/activate/aoisdoaisdoaisdoiaj/`
I am taken to an activation_failed page which says - `The activation key you provided is invalid`.
But my account in the database gets activated too.

If the account is being activated that means activation was successful, then why would django-registration redirect to failed page?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 urls in django-registration/backends/activation/urls.py that create complications which is hard to figure out for a django rookie like myself :
Lets call them url1 and url2 as per order shown below.

1. `"activate/complete/"`
2. `"activate/<str:activation_key>/"`

They are strategically ordered in original urls.py. But since I overwrote ActivationView class, I had to overwrite the url2 `"activate/<str:activation_key>/"`. That changed the original order and django started looking for url2 before url1. As you can see that any url of format `/activate/xyz/` can qualify as url2. Hence /activate/complete/ also called view in url2.

Solution: change name of url1 to something like `activation/complete/` and it all works fine

That put

Answer (score 0):

You are being redirected to `activation/complete/` and your custom activation URL is catching this URL. To restore the built in behavior, add a URL pattern above your custom activation URL like so:

```
path("activate/complete/", 
         TemplateView.as_view(template_name="django_registration/activation_complete.html"),
         name="django_registration_activation_complete")
```